# Simple website doesn't work on server

Tags: asp.net

i have a very simple websote just for experimentation.
On my local machine it works but when i put it on the server i get "Server Error in '/' Application.Runtime Error "

defaul.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_default"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But when i change the aspx file it works (i've removed:CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" and Inherits="_default")

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: define "doesn't work" - do you get an error?

Comment: i edited the post. i get "Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error "

Comment: in your app config file, change Custom error settings and see the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if i remove the `System.Linq` from my aspx.cs file the site does work.

Comment: Is it because your webserver is running .NET 2.0?

Comment: It says that it supports .NET Framework 1.1, 2.0, 3.5, 4.0. So i don't got a clue why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Framework version correct for the application pool on the server?

You've stated that it works if you remove System.Linq which could point at the Framework version being incorrect on the application pool

The other thing to check is to make sure you're not running sites built on different version of the .Net framework in the same application pool as they will kill each other and you'll get the dreaded "Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error"

Answer (score 0):

Please check two dlls must be in your Bin folder on the server

1) System.Web.Extensions.dll
2) System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll